# query between dates returns rows from previous months too

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have the following where clause

```
AND  DATE_FORMAT( l.created_on,  "%d/%m/%Y" )  BETWEEN '06/02/2013' AND '07/02/2013'
```

where `created_on` is a timestamp.

Now for some reason the query returns rows from previous months as well. anyone knows why?

**NOTE :**

**I need the date to be in that specific format**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `created_on` is already a date (*datatype*),

you can directly query it using,

```
WHERE created_on  BETWEEN '2013-02-06' AND '2013-02-07'
```

but if date is a string, use `STR_TO_DATE`

```
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(l.created_on,  '%d-%m-%Y')  BETWEEN '2013-02-06' AND '2013-02-07'
```

**UPDATE 1**

since you don't want to change the format of your inputted date, then you need to format it using `STR_TO_DATE`

```
WHERE l.created_on  BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('06/02/2013','%d/%m/%Y') AND 
                            STR_TO_DATE('07/02/2013','%d/%m/%Y')
```

Comment: it's timestamp. if i do that i get no results.

Comment: And your second option also returns no results when there are results.

Comment: well, if that's the case then you should be converting the values, not the column, eg `WHERE l.created_on  BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('06/02/2013','%d/%m/%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('07/02/2013','%d/%m/%Y')`

Comment: Well this seemed to work. edit your question and i'll accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Mysql string date format follows pattern yyyy-mm-dd. Do not convert to dates if you have timestamps, just compare the timestamps.

```
WHERE l.created_on 
BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2012/02/06') AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013/02/07')
```

Comment: You are all reformating my date! i am using that specific format and can't change it, and if i try your code with my format i get no results.

Comment: @eric.itzhak What you mean? Nothing changed. What specific format?

Comment: Your date is yyyy-mm-dd while my string is mm/dd/yyyy. But it's okay thank you JW's answer seemed to work.

Comment: mysql does not understand nor accept dates in your desired format, without parsing. You can parse the value with SR_TO_DATE as suggested below, but it is *WRONG* and I won't modify my answer to explain that.

Comment: @eric.itzhak "where created_on is a timestamp." Is your `created_on` of datatype `timestmp` or `varchar`?

Comment: @guido the OP commented on the deleted answer of fthiella: *"..i get the date in that specific format and have no intention to change in in code before query"* and that's the reason why i introduce `STR_TO_DATE`. and what's wrong with that?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan it's timestamp not varchar.